# How to disable blk-mq for NVMe and use CFQ, deadline, noop?

Tags: io, linux-kernel, scheduler

For testing purposes, I would like to use `CFQ`, `deadline`, and `noop` for an NVMe drive. Is this possible?

I am able to use the blk-mq for SATA SSDs by adding `"scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1"` to the grub boot (see: [How to enable and use the BFQ scheduler?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375600/how-to-enable-and-use-the-bfq-scheduler)).

But have yet to find a way to do the reverse for NVMe drives to allow them to use the non blk-mq schedulers.